# Migrating Azure VM through Azure Migrate and getting below error when installing mobility service on premise server

Tags: azure-site-recovery, azure-migrate

I am migrating Azure VM  using Azure Migrate and getting below error when installing mobility service on premise server, tried running through cmd prompt still same error.
any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the azure VMs migration from one region to other, you need to use command line installation method only.

If you are getting the same error with the UI method of installation, then it most likely is an issue with the setup file.
Uninstall if there is any partial installation done through control panel and follow the below

Recommendation:
The best way to migrate Azure VMs between the azure regions is not azure migrate, you need to use Azure Resource Mover. It takes care of installing mobility agent through push installer.
Here is the documentation on azure resource mover https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-virtual-machines

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-physical-mobility-service-overview#install-the-mobility-service-using-command-prompt-classic

[image]